# react native flatlist not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've been experimenting with react native and I cannot get my `FlatList` to render correctly. Here is the component. If it matters, I am using `react-navigation` to render this component.

```
class FactoryScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'test test',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      datasource: [
        {
          id: 21, machine_key: 'f', clamp_id: 'c0',
        },
        {
          id: 22, machine_key: 'f', clamp_id: 'c1',
        },
        {
          id: 23, machine_key: 'f', clamp_id: 'c2',
        },
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <List style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.datasource}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            console.log(item);
            return (<ListItem title={`${item.clamp_id} clamp`} />);
          }}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

I can see my `item` object get logged to the console but I can't get it to render for whatever reason. Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: kindly check your ListItem component, I can display your data with: return (<Text>{item.clamp_id} clamp</Text>);

Comment: @KimHau unfortunately even though I switched it to your code, I wasn't able to see it show up.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't React Navigation

First make sure your `<LisItem>` component can display data. If this component from native-base make sure double check the `List` component documentation [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref)

Than you need key extractor for this. here's the example

```
... 

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

  render() {
    return (
      <List style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.datasource}
          keyExtractor = {this._keyExtractor} 
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            console.log(item);
            return ( <Text>{`${item.clamp_id} clamp`} clamp</Text>); 
          }}          
        />
      </List>

    );
  }

...
```

Comment: thank you for this, unfortunately while the key extractor error went away, I still cannot see the list show up. I also stopped using `ListItem` and used `Text` just in case, but that doesn't seem to have solved it.

Comment: no error message showed up, it just fails silently. I opened up an issue with react-navigation, because I got it to work when my code is outside of `StackNavigation` but as soon as I put it in the screen, it doesn't. See more here: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2135